# how to implement a map with multiple lists in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have N FIFO queues to support efficient insert at tail and remove at head. Meanwhile I would like to support efficient lookup of the data in the queues, what is the best way to achieve this in Java?

One solution is to implement a linkedHashmap for each queue. However, to find the data, it needs to perform N lookups. Is there a better way to do this?

The solution mentioned above

```
Map<Id, Value> q1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Value> q2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Value> q3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Value> q4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// to read a key, I have to do the following
if (q1.contains(id)) {
  return q1.get(id);
} else if (q2.contains(id)) {
  return q2.get(id);
} else if (q3.contains(id)) {
  return q3.get(id);
} else if (q4.contains(id)) {
  return q4.get(id);
}
```

I guess I can have a map storing the categorization, which will limit the lookups to two, but means that I have to waste some memory.

EDIT 1:
An example
Data are put in different lists based on access patterns. For example, data that has been accessed once is stored in list 1, and upon the second request, the data is moved to list 2.

One can think about this as an LFU  cache where each list is responsible for one frequency. In addition to the lists, I need to have an efficient lookup to find the data.

Comment: If faster access is the only usecase then we can use a nested-map.
e.g., `Map<list_key, Map<key, value>>`

Elaborate more if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: @RishabhDuttSharma I need ordering between elements, that's why I have N linkedlists. Do I misunderstand this?

Comment: Likely down-voted because your Question is so unclear. Why did you mention "linkedlist" rather than `List`; is there some significance related to your Question? You say "map interface for lookup", but you do not explain exactly what you want to lookup nor do you explain by what criteria will you drive that search? Do you mean you want to access any one particular of your many lists? If so, what is the criteria, what would be the key in your map? And, what does "N lookups" mean? That same letter "N" was used for the count of your "linkedlists" — do you mean the same number? All quite confusing.

Comment: A simplistic contrived example would *really* improve your Question. A stab at some code would help too.

Comment: Define "better".  Be specific about your concern. Faster in CPU? More efficient with memory? Easier to read by programmers? More likely to be compatible in some way?

Comment: Why would you have multiple queues if they are not somehow categorized? And, if categorized, why would you not know which queue holds which kind of items? If I have a queue for dogs, and another for cats, and a third for birds, why would I expect to find a cat in either the dog queue or the bird queue?

Comment: Thank you! @BasilBourque Better in terms of fewer hash lookups. The categorization is not part of the key. I guess I can have a map storing the categorization, which will limit the lookup to two, but it means that I have to waste some memory...

Comment: Why would you have multiple queues if not to segregate their contents? Answering that question is key to getting a worthy Answer for your Question.

Comment: Also, you need to be posting these clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. Then there is a possibility of re-opening the Question.

Comment: The segregation is based on request pattern, e.g., data that has been accessed once is stored in list 1, upon the second request, the data is moved to the second list. I will update the question. Thank you!

Comment: Is any given item ever stored in more than one `Queue`/`Map`?

Comment: Why do you keep talking about “list” and even tag the question with `[linked-list]`when there is not a single list in your example? Placing a bounty will not provide you better answers when your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Given the `LFU (Least Frequently Used) cache-like behavior described, the following design can achieve your goals:

- Doubly Linked List: Since we need to move items around frequently
  (especially between different frequency queues), a doubly linked list
  can serve this purpose well.
- HashMap for Direct Access: This hashmap will be responsible for
  direct access to a specific node given a key (which means efficient
  lookups). The value stored in this hashmap would be the reference to
  the node in the doubly linked list.
- Array of LinkedHashMaps: To maintain the frequency queues (based on
  how many times the data has been accessed), you can use an array of
  LinkedHashMaps (or doubly linked lists if you want to manually manage
  the ordering). Each LinkedHashMap will maintain the order of
  insertion which represents the frequency of usage

  ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class test {


       public static class LFUQueue<K, V> {

           private Map<K, Node<K, V>> lookupMap;
           private Map<Integer, LinkedHashMap<K, Node<K, V>>> frequencyMap;

           public LFUQueue(int maxFrequency) {
               lookupMap = new HashMap<>();
               frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

               for (int i = 0; i <= maxFrequency; i++) {
                   frequencyMap.put(i, new LinkedHashMap<>());
               }
           }

           public V get(K key) {
               if (!lookupMap.containsKey(key)) {
                   return null;
               }
               Node<K, V> node = lookupMap.get(key);

               // Remove from current frequency list
               frequencyMap.get(node.frequency).remove(key);

               // Increase frequency
               node.frequency++;
               if (!frequencyMap.containsKey(node.frequency)) {
                   frequencyMap.put(node.frequency, new LinkedHashMap<>());
               }

               // Add to next frequency list
               frequencyMap.get(node.frequency).put(key, node);

               return node.value;
           }

           public void put(K key, V value) {
               if (lookupMap.containsKey(key)) {
                   // Update value and frequency
                   Node<K, V> node = lookupMap.get(key);
                   node.value = value;
                   get(key); // This will handle frequency update as well
               } else {
                   Node<K, V> newNode = new Node<>(key, value);
                   lookupMap.put(key, newNode);
                   frequencyMap.get(0).put(key, newNode);
               }
           }

           public int getFrequency(K key) {
               Node<K, V> node = lookupMap.get(key);
               return node != null ? node.frequency : -1;
           }
       }

       static class Node<K, V> {
           K key;
           V value;
           int frequency;
           Node<K, V> prev;
           Node<K, V> next;

           Node(K key, V value) {
               this.key = key;
               this.value = value;
               this.frequency = 0; // start at 0 access
           }

       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           LFUQueue<String, String> lfu = new LFUQueue<>(5);

           // Add some elements
           lfu.put("one", "First Value");
           lfu.put("two", "Second Value");
           lfu.put("three", "Third Value");

           // Access an element to increase its frequency
           System.out.println("Accessing 'one': " + lfu.get("one"));
           System.out.println("Accessing 'one': " + lfu.get("one"));

           // Access another element
           System.out.println("Accessing 'two': " + lfu.get("two"));

           // Insert new element
           lfu.put("four", "Fourth Value");

           // Access 'four' multiple times
           System.out.println("Accessing 'four': " + lfu.get("four"));
           System.out.println("Accessing 'four': " + lfu.get("four"));
           System.out.println("Accessing 'four': " + lfu.get("four"));

           // Verify the frequency behavior
           // Assuming a simple method to get frequency is implemented in LFUQueue
           System.out.println("'one' frequency: " + lfu.getFrequency("one"));
           System.out.println("'two' frequency: " + lfu.getFrequency("two"));
           System.out.println("'four' frequency: " + lfu.getFrequency("four"));
       }
   }
  ```

The result:
[image]

Given the LFU (Least Frequently Used) cache-like behavior described, the following design can achieve your goals:

Doubly Linked List: Since we need to move items around frequently (especially between different frequency queues), a doubly linked list can serve this purpose well.

HashMap for Direct Access: This hashmap will be responsible for direct access to a specific node given a key (which means efficient lookups). The value stored in this hashmap would be the reference to the node in the doubly linked list.

Array of LinkedHashMaps: To maintain the frequency queues (based on how many times the data has been accessed), you can use an array of LinkedHashMaps (or doubly linked lists if you want to manually manage the ordering). Each LinkedHashMap will maintain the order of insertion which represents the frequency of usage.

The lookupMap allows you to get direct access to any key in O(1) time.

Whenever you access a key (using the get method), the frequency of that key is increased. The node representing this key-value pair is moved from its current frequency list to the next one (indicating an increase in access frequency).

The frequencyMap allows you to efficiently get items based on their frequency and maintain them in the order they were accessed (or inserted).

This solution ensures that:

- Insertion is O(1).
- Lookup is O(1).
- Frequency update (due to access) is O(1).
- Deletion (if implemented) would also be O(1).
  Given the structure of the `LFUQueue` you provided, let's break down the time complexity of each operation:

1. **Insertion**:

   - Checking if a key exists in `lookupMap`: O(1) due to HashMap's average time complexity for lookup.
   - Inserting into `lookupMap`: O(1) average case.
   - Inserting into the corresponding `frequencyMap`: O(1) average case.

   **Conclusion**: Overall, the insertion is O(1) on average. However, remember that HashMap can have a worst-case time complexity of O(n) when a hash collision occurs. In practice, with a good hashing mechanism and resizing strategy, it rarely happens.
2. **Lookup**:

   - Checking and retrieving a key from `lookupMap`: O(1) on average.

   **Conclusion**: The lookup is O(1) on average.
3. **Frequency update (due to access)**:

   - Retrieving a node from `lookupMap`: O(1) on average.
   - Removing the node from its current frequency list in `frequencyMap`: O(1) because we're using a LinkedHashMap and we have direct access to the node.
   - Inserting the node into the next frequency list in `frequencyMap`: O(1) on average.

   **Conclusion**: Frequency update is O(1) on average.
4. **Deletion (if implemented)**:

   - Retrieving a node from `lookupMap`: O(1) on average.
   - Removing the node from its current frequency list in `frequencyMap`: O(1) for LinkedHashMap.
   - Removing the node from `lookupMap`: O(1) on average.

   **Conclusion**: Deletion would be O(1) on average.

It's worth noting that the worst-case time complexity for many of the HashMap and LinkedHashMap operations is O(n), but this worst-case scenario is quite rare in practice with a good hash function and is usually averaged out over time to provide consistent O(1) performance. However, if you have concerns about worst-case performance (e.g., due to potential adversarial input), you may want to consider using a data structure with guaranteed worst-case O(1) behavior or take steps to mitigate potential collisions in your hash function.

Answer (score 1):

You need one more collection in your code that maps id to collection it was inserted into:

```
Map<Id, Value> q1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Value> q2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Value> q3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Value> q4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Id, Map<Id, Value>> mainQueue = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

When you map an id:

```
q1.put(id, value);
mainQueue.put(id, q1);
```

// to read a key, do the following

```
if(mainQueue.contains(id)){
    return mainQueue.get(id).get(id);
}
```

Another approach:

```
return List.of(q1,q2,q3,q4).stream().filter(q -> q.contains(id)).findFirst().get().get(id);
```

Comment: The OP said: "I guess I can have a map storing the categorization, which will limit the lookup to two, but it means that I have to waste some memory".

Comment: The only other option I can imagine: List.of(q1,q2,q3,q4).stream().filter(q -> q.contains(id)).findFirst()

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use a global `HashMap`:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static class MultiQueue<K, V>
    {
        private LinkedList<V>[] queues;
        private HashMap<K, V> map;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public MultiQueue(int n)
        {
            queues = new LinkedList[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                queues[i] = new LinkedList<V>();
            map = new HashMap<K, V>();
        }

        public void add(K id, V value, int queue)
        {
            queues[queue].addFirst(value);
            map.put(id, value);
        }

        public V get(K id)
        {
            return map.get(id);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MultiQueue<Integer, String> mq = new MultiQueue<>(2);
        mq.add(10, "Item 10", 0); // add to first queue
        mq.add(20, "Item 20", 1); // add to second queue
        System.out.println(mq.get(10));
        System.out.println(mq.get(20));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item 10
Item 20
```

Comment: The global map doesn't prioritise q1 over q2 over q3...

Comment: @greybeard As far as I understand, a value is present in only one queue (the OP said that data could be "moved" from one queue to the other).

Comment: (`OP said[…]` …in a comment - I added an explicit request for clarification there.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified whether or not any given `Id` can occur in more than one FIFO.

Assuming strict FIFO `add()`/`remove()` & somewhat frequent lookups, cases:

0. Any given ID can occur in one queue out of *N*, at most - use

   - a single Map<Id, Value> (I'd choose `java.util.HashMap<>`)
   - *N* `Queue<Id>`s
     insert into queue as required, putting in map, too
     when removing from last queue/for good, remove from map
     when removing from any other queue and reinserting, the mapping doesn't need to be changed
1. Any given ID can occur in 0 to *N* queues
   I didn't come up with anything better than the `Map<Id, "LinkedMap"<Id, Value>>` [Rishabh Dutt Sharma](/questions/76950164/map-with-multiple-lists#comment135653082_76950164)
    and [you yourself](/questions/76950164/map-with-multiple-lists#comment135666003_76950164)
   mention in comments.

Drawing heavily on [Shila Mosammami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021177/3789665):

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

/** Multiple (N) queues supporting: <br/>
 *  - addition to queue by ordinal  <br/>
 *  - removal by key (O(N))         <br/>
 *  - removal by ordinal            <br/>
 *  - map                           <br/>
 * no key shall be put into more than one queue. (Try and remove?)
 */// ToDo: decide visibility of method members
public class MultiQueue<K, V>
{
    private Queue<K>[] queues;
    private Map<K, V> map;

//    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MultiQueue(final int n) {
        queues = new Queue/*<V>*/[n];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            queues[i] = new ArrayDeque</*V*/>();
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(final K id, V value, int queue) {
        queues[queue].add(id);
        map.put(id, value);
    }
    /** Remove <code>key</code> and associated data for good. <br/>
     *  ToDo: specify behaviour when <code>key</code> not first in any queue.<br/>
     *        (currently just returns <code>null</code>.)
     *  @return key removed, else <code>null</code>
     */
    V remove(final K key) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < queues.length ; i++)
            if (queues[i].peek() == key)
                return remove(i);
        return null;
    }
    /** Remove first from queue. <br/>
     *  @return value for key removed, else <code>null</code>
     */
    V remove(int queue) {
        K key = queues[queue].poll();
        return map.remove(key);
    }
    /** Move one item from queue <code>from</code> to queue <code>to</code>. <br/>
     *  ToDo: What shall happen when <code>from == to</code>?
     *  @return key moved, else <code>null</code>
     */
    K move(int from, int to) {
        K moving = queues[from].poll();
        if (null == moving)
            return null;
        queues[to].add(moving);
        return moving;
    }
    // XXX isolation?
    Queue<K> queue(int queue) { return queues[queue]; }

    public V get(K id)
    {
        return map.get(id);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        for (Queue<K> q: queues) {
            sb.append('(');
            if (q.isEmpty())
                sb.append("), ");
            else {
                for (K k: q)
                    sb.append(k).append('(').append(map.get(k)).append("), ");
                sb.insert(sb.length()-2, ')');
            }
        }
        return sb.replace(sb.length()-2, sb.length(), "]").toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MultiQueue<Integer, String> mq = new MultiQueue<>(2);
        mq.add(10, "Item 10", 0); // add to first queue
        mq.add(20, "Item 20", 1); // add to second queue
        System.out.println("10: " + mq.get(10));
        System.out.println("20: " + mq.get(20));
        mq.add(10, "Item 13", 1); // add to second queue
        // bad luck well deserved 
        //  for breaking "contract" to enter a key to one queue at most. 
        System.out.println("10: " + mq.get(10));
        mq.move(0, 1);
        System.out.println("moved: " + mq.get(10));
        System.out.println(mq);
    }
}
```